# is it open covering for $[0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I have a question when I study 'topology'

In my thought, 
$$O=\{{(C_i,C_{i+1}) | C_i \in (0,1) \cap \mathbb{Q}^c,  C_i＜C_{i+1}}\}$$ 
is an open covering for $[0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}$.

Is the infinite union of the elements of $O$ equal to $[0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}$?

It's very confusing me.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Besides, what are $a$ and $b$?

Comment: And what are the $C_i$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos sorry. a and b are 0 and 1.

Comment: @user60589 Ci's are all irrational number between 0 and 1.

Comment: Okay, but those $i$ make them look like they are countable (indexed over the integers) right? Maybe just use $C,C'$. If they are in between $0$ and $1$, how could $0$ and $1$ be in the cover?

Comment: @user60589 Thank you for the advise : C,C'. It really looks like they are countable. And now i can understand what you mean. Thank you :)

Comment: I guess you want to show that $[0,1] \cap \Bbb Q$ is not compact? So it is a good idea to make the $C_i$ more precise. (Indexed over $\Bbb N$ wouldn'd be a bad choice here)

Comment: No element $O$ that you've described contains $0$.

Comment: @user60589 Yes. Actually i want to prove that. Could you let me know the expression for $ C_i$ more precise as a collection of open set in $Q∩[0,1]$?

Comment: Just pick an irrational number $c$ and try to vary it by something like $\frac{1}{i}$ such that it fits inside the interval.